# Translation related post text to Arabic

Tags: posts, post-meta, get-posts, multi-language, plugin-polylang

I have website with Arabic and English language,the main language is English, I used polylang and loco plugin for translation, I used elementor plugin, the title of related post is input value in post customise, how to translate it to be Related post in English site and مقالات ذات صلة in Arabic site

Comment: You will need to ask the authors of the plugins you are using. How they work together is something only they can tell you.